# Select the last matched url using regex in an uncomment line

Tags: regex

Wanted to capture the url after deb. The line should not start with `#`. Will be the last match.

```
#deb http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/nope/ bullseye main contrib non-free rpi
deb http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/notthis/ bullseye main contrib non-free rpi
deb http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/select/ bullseye main contrib non-free rpi
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/nana/ bullseye main contrib non-free rpi
```

Closest I got is: `(?<=deb\s)(.*?)(?=\s)`

Comment: `(?m)[\w\W]*^(?!#).*deb\s+\K\S+` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/yIwsN4/3)) or  `(?m)[\w\W]*^(?!#).*deb\s+(\S+)` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/yIwsN4/4))

Comment: Thank you @Wiktor. An explanation would be helpful.

Comment: Which one worked?

Comment: 1st one is the better. However, in Python `\K` not worked as intended. I will be using this with ansible (python based).

Comment: So, `(?m)[\w\W]*^(?!#).*deb\s+(\S+)` is what you need. Use it with `re_search` and use the `1` argument to get the group value.

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
(?:[\w\W]*\n)?(?!#).*deb\s+(\S+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yIwsN4/7).

*Details*:

- `(?:[\w\W]*\n)?` - an optional sequence of any zero or more chars as many as possible and then a newline char
- `(?!#)` - right after the newline char, there must be no `#`
- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `deb` - literal substring
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `(\S+)` - Capturing group 1: one or more whitespaces.

Comment: FYI, in ansible, it will look like ``regex_search('(?:[\\w\\W]*\\n)?(?!#).*deb\\s+(\\S+)', '\\1')``

Comment: @wicktor, I'm using `ansible.builtin.replace` module. With `regexp: "^(?!#)(?:[\\w\\W]*\\n)?.*deb\\s+(\\S+)"` It is replacing with the match 1 group 0, not the match 1 group 1. I don't know it is the issue with ansible or what. If I use `^(?!#)(?:[\w\W]*\n)?.*deb\s+(\S+)` in [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/OOr0Ae/1) it clearly shows the selection is right. This is the same with your code too.

Comment: @Dr.PB A regex for extraction can only be used in an *extracting* method. Use `regex_search` as I showed. Replacing can be achieved, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/yIwsN4/8), but I'd use extraction here.